# how I can show position of an object ( a mark) which have coordinate on database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, coordinates

I have a database and there is writing point numbers, x and y pixsel coordinates. I want to show that points on webpage. I can show only one point (last one).

How I can show all of them on webpage in sametime?

can anyone help me? where is the my mistake?

```
<?php
ob_start();

$image = imagecreatetruecolor(800, 600);
$red = imagecolorallocate($image, 250, 0, 0);

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxx","yyyyy");
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM points"); 
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

while($select=mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) 

$id = $select['id'];
$x = $select['x'];
$y = $select['y'];

for ( $i=0; $i < count($x); $i++ ) 
imagefilledellipse($image, $x[$i], $y[$i], 10, 10, $red);


header( 'Content-type: image/jpeg' );
ob_end_flush(); 
ob_end_clean(); 
imagepng( $image );

?>
```

Comment: How far have you gotten? There are a lot of ways to do this, from generating an image to using a canvas.

Comment: Thank you for your interest @BarryCarter. I have a SVG image on webpage. I want to show a mark on this SVG page with taking coordinates from database.

Comment: I founded some scripts from stacowerflow and other websites. But those are does not work as I want. Or I couldnt find a way for use that correctly.

Comment: Still a bit ambiguous ... Do you want to place an element _within_ the SVG at a specific position, in relation to the SVG's coordinate set, or do you just want to position the SVG itself absolute using CSS, or ... what, _exactly_?

Comment: If you could show us a test site with the code you have, it would be helpful; however, specific questions like this (whose answers benefit only one person) are usually closed

Comment: @CBroe; thank you... I want to place an element or object within the SVG at a specific position with coordinate which are take from DB. pixel coordinate.

Comment: I get it @BarryCarter. I will try to share a sample codes or test site. Thank you.

Comment: @CBroe and BarryCarter can help me for change to that SESSION's to DATABASE connection?

Comment: What have you tried, and what problem did you run into?

Comment: thank you for your quick reply @CBroe; This coords.php writing coordinate to SESSION's and then reading that coordinates and marked to page. I want use MYSQL database for record coordinate values and then read from database and show them on page. I have correct DB tables, connections. I want to change SESSION's to connection DB.

Comment: I did not ask you to repeat what you _want_ in slightly different terms, I asked you what you tried to actually implement it. You are asking for our help - so you need to be specific, as to what you actually need help _with_. We are not here to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe provide more information on this topic.

This might help you? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php

Comment: thank you @sme3x , but it is too complex for me. I need to change that SESSINON's with MYSQL database. This coords.php , first writing to SESSION and then reading that. I need send coordinates to database and then read from DB without SESSION's. thank you.